# Can a resistance be negative?

Tags: resistance, negative

I have to calculate the value of a resistor so that my circuit has a certain equivalent resistance. This is the circuit, and here are the values:

```
Ig = 5 mA, R1 = 2 kΩ and R2 = 1 kΩ. R3 is unknown.
```

[image: Circuit]

So I want to know the value of R3 for a equivalent resistance  of 5kΩ.
Well, what I do first, is calculate the resistance of R1+R3, and then add R2, which its R13+R2 :
[image]

So, I replace this for the values :

[image]

But if I resolve this, I always get a value of -4kΩ. So whats happening?
Am I doing anything wrong? or can a resistance be negative like this?

Comment: *"Am I doing anything wrong?"* Well, if you get a negative resistance all your alarm bells should start ringing (Yes, you are doing something wrong). Please tell us how much current do you think is passing through R2?

Comment: Im sorry, this is my first week studiying electronics and english is not my first language so im not sure if I understand you. R2 is 1000Ω so it should has that currency. Please tell me if you dont understand me or I can explain anything better.

Comment: Let me be more specific: Stop doing any calculations and look at the diagram, where would the current through R2 come from and where would it go to?

Comment: @Fran I'd like to mention that if a n/w (I abbreviated 'Network' as 'n/w') contains dependent sources, Thevenin's resistance _may_ come out to be negative in certain cases. (In case you're not familiar with what is Thevenin's resistance, you'll learn in pretty soon, most probably in same course you're going through)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that you have a current source and not a voltage source. In this case, when using Thevenin you should replace the current source by an open circuit to find the equivalent resistance (as opposed to replace by a short if you have a voltage source). Therefore, the equivalent resistance will not be R1//R3 + R2 as you've assumed. Actually the solution is much simpler (I'll let you finish it).

Let's suppose that you did everything right and ended up with a negative resistance. That would simply tell you that there is no solution to the problem (what is not the case here).

Comment: I think I got it, if Ig is a short, that means that the resistance between that and R1 is = 0 , so for the Req from A to B will be R2+R1, is this ritght?

Comment: You should look from the side of nodes A and B. Replacing Ig by an OPEN, the value of R1 doesn't really matter (the circuit is open on the left side of R1), and the resistance between A and B will be simply R2 + R3.

Comment: Omg I resolved it right but wrote it incorrectly, my supossition was right. Thank you so much.

Comment: No problem. Welcome to the community!

Answer (score 1):

Just answering the question (title) - without reference to the presented diagram:

Yes, of course, a resistance can be negative !!

- The I-V characteristic of a tunnel diode (Esaki diode) shows in a certain range a negative dynamic (differential) resistance (hence, not a static negative resistance)
- There are special active circuits (NIC- Negative Impedance Converter) which have a negative (single-side grounded) input resistance (staic and differential)
- Both parts/circuits are used - for example - in oscillator circuits for undamping purposes (compensation of classic positive ohmic resistances).